# El vinculo al blog post sobre 2016, dice 2017

Tags: bug, estado-completado

En la pagina principal del sitio, dice "El estado de Stack Overflow en español Diciembre 2017", el post vinculado dice 2016, ademas de que diciembre de 2017 no ha llegado XD.

Evidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que ya se arregló.

Comment: Welcome to the future.